# Как подсчитать очки в турнире на основе pandas.DataFrame с результатами игр

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, pandas, dataframe

Есть df в который добавляются результаты игр команд:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'h_title': ('Sparta', 'Boor', 'Sachs', 'Boor', 'T-Rax'),
                        'h_goals': (0, 2, 5, 1, 2),
                        'a_title': ('Boor', 'Sachs', 'Sparta', 'T-Rax', 'Sparta'),
                        'a_goals': (4, 2, 1, 2, 2)})
```

Подскажите как создать функцию, которая будет определять результат по количеству голов и обновлять данные словаря:

```
team_dict = {i : 0 for i in ds['h_title']}
```

Команда победитель получит +3 очка в value, и по 1-му очку получают обе при ничьей.

Те вывод team_dict на основе df в текущем состоянии получится:

{'Sparta': 1, 'Boor': 4, 'Sachs': 4, 'T-Rax': 4}

К сожалению моих знаний пока не хватает, чтобы решить эту несложную задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def score(df):
    h_vals = (df.eval("h_goals > a_goals") * 3 + df.eval("h_goals == a_goals") * 1).to_numpy()
    h = pd.Series(h_vals, index=df["h_title"]).sum(level=0)
    a_vals = (df.eval("h_goals < a_goals") * 3 + df.eval("h_goals == a_goals") * 1).to_numpy()
    a = pd.Series(a_vals, index=df["a_title"]).sum(level=0)
    return a+h
```

---

```
In [114]: score(df)
Out[114]:
a_title
Boor      4
Sachs     4
Sparta    1
T-Rax     4
dtype: int32
```

---

```
In [115]: score(df).to_dict()
Out[115]: {'Boor': 4, 'Sachs': 4, 'Sparta': 1, 'T-Rax': 4}
```

Comment: не по теме, можете посоветовать что-нить почитать про pandas и иже с ними, хочу просветиться, вдруг пригодится :)

Comment: @splash58, начать стоит [отсюда](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html), а дальше хорошо было бы придумать себе небольшой проект, где можно использовать Pandas...

Comment: @splash58, простые вещи последовательно здесь можно практиковать:
https://praktikum.yandex.ru/profile/data-analyst/

Comment: @MaxU был не за компом, поэтому не сразу. Спасибо! Про проекты - это несомненно. Один есть, но боюсь, хоть там и возня с экспериментальными анными, но боюсь, не очень много мне даст в смысле этой практики, но всяко подготовлюсь, мало ли :)

Comment: @SergeiKorneev похоже, отличная ссылка для старта